# Missing argument Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm getting the error:

```
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.default,
│   on main.tf line 126, in data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "default":
│  126:   name = module.eks.cluster_id
│ 
│ The argument "name" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with data.aws_eks_cluster.default,
│   on main.tf line 122, in data "aws_eks_cluster" "default":
│  122:   name = module.eks.cluster_id
│ 
│ The argument "name" is required, but no definition was found.
```

This is my Terraform script:

```
module "eks" {
...
}

data "aws_eks_cluster" "default" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id <============= HERE ARE THE LINES OF THE ERROR
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "default" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id <============= HERE ARE THE LINES OF THE ERROR
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.default.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.default.certificate_authority[0].data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.default.token
}
```

This is exactly like in [this](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v17.24.0/examples/complete/main.tf#L185) example.

Can someone please give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT 0:

Terraform config. Notice that the `kubernetes` provider is exactly like in the [example](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v17.24.0/examples/complete/versions.tf#L15).:

```
terraform {


  cloud {
    organization = "abc"

    workspaces {
      name = "abc00"
    }
  }

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.7.0"
    }

    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "~> 3.5.1"
    }

    tls = {
      source  = "hashicorp/tls"
      version = "~> 4.0.4"
    }

    cloudinit = {
      source  = "hashicorp/cloudinit"
      version = "~> 2.3.2"
    }

    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 1.11.1"
    }

  }

  required_version = "~> 1.3"
}
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `module.eks.cluster_id`? It could be `null`, which would explain your error.

Comment: That example is primarily valid for kubernetes provider version <= 2.3.3. The module and provider versions are both currently absent from the question. Also the above comment is a potential root cause.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the feedback!! Will think about it and get back soon ;)

Comment: If the `eks` module is creating an EKS cluster, you should directly use the cluster that is output from the module, instead of taking the output from the module and proceeding to lookup the cluster again as a data source.

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard I added the kubernetes version to my question.

Answer (score 0):

as marcin mentioned, the key to the answer is in the eks module.

for "module.eks.cluster_id" to return any data, the eks module itself needs to have a section that looks something like this:

```
output "cluster_id" {
  description = "The ID of the cluster."
  value       = aws_eks_cluster.this.cluster_id
}
```

you could also add an output section in the root terraform code to display the value, as follows:

```
output "debug_cluster_id" {
  value = module.eks.cluster_id
}
```

when terraform plan or apply is run, this data will be displayed in the console output allowing you to view the result which will allow analyzing the data and making adjustments, as needed. when troubleshooting is done, the root module output can be commented out or deleted.